# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer datetime datetime found

Tags: python

This is my script to save the output into a `csv` file:

```
import os, csv, datefinder, datetime
os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Desktop\Article')

with open("test2.txt", 'r') as file1:
  text1 = file1.read()

matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))

if len(matches) > 0:
    date = matches[1]
    print date
else:
    print 'No dates found'

csv = open(date, "w")

columnTitleRow = "date, time\n"
csv.write(columnTitleRow)
```

When I run this script, I get this error message:

[Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dul\Desktop\Article\ap.py", line 18, in  csv = open(date, "w")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found]

Comment: Next time please add the full error stacktrace to your question. That helps us to see in which line the error happens and which underlying function is raising the error.

Comment: @Ralf Ok. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a `datetime` instance to `open()`; that function needs a string that indicates the filename of the file it should open.

Are you sure that you need to open a file that has the name of the date?
If that really is you case, then you need to at least cast the `datetime` object to a `str`:

```
csv = open(str(date), "w")
```

But I doubt that that really is what you need.